# What exactly happened at the end of Kamisama no Inai Nichiyoubi?

Tags: sunday-without-god

Kamisama no Inai Nichiyoubi (神さまのいない日曜日) ended with more questions than answers:

- If Alice died instead of Dee, then why was Dee the one as a ghost in the real world?
  Furthermore, Dee has her body (in the outside world) in the final scene.
- How does Ai managed to "save" Alice? Yet at the same time she's standing in front of his grave.

Running through the forums and it seems like I'm not the only one who's confused.

---

What in the world happened? (no pun intended)

The biggest and undeniable contradiction is Dee going from ghost to normal human.
Does this mean that some sort of change of history caused Dee and Alice to "switch places"?

Answer (score 3):

- Dee appeared as a ghost because her physical body was still stuck in class 3-4, while Alice had a physical body outside because he was already buried by a proper gravekeeper. Therefore, his body wasn't in class 3-4 like Dee, and could appear normally since he was part of the world outside.
- Dee has a physical body later on, because the world class 3-4 created had been destroyed. Her physical body was released.
- Ai saved Alice by wishing intensely. In *Sunday Without God*, by wishing for something really badly it somehow would be granted, like how Hampnie Hambart wished to die happily besides his family, or how Alice got the ability Buzzer Beater. When Ai wished for Alice to be saved, God granted that wish, and so Alice could have a physical body outside class 3-4's world and continue to live his life.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation was that:

> This was a world where people frequently get special powers by wishing intensely.  Intense wishes can cause perfect aim with Buzzer Beater, special power to eat normally inedible objects, and even a giant time loop when 17 people wish all at once.  The fact that Dee appeared to be the ghost was probably part of the wish of those 17 people.  They wished for a world that would never be disturbed by reality, and their wish made Dee appear as a ghost outside, because that made their world less likely to be disturbed by reality.
>
>  In this story, God makes rules that are more like loose guidelines, and God breaks His own guidelines frequently.  The gravekeeper Scar wasn't supposed to be able to cry, but apparently she wished to be more normal and  God transformed her - apparently into a normal woman.
>
>  At the end of the story, just before Ai was pushed out of the room, she was wishing with all her heart that she could find some way to save everyone.  I presume God granted her wish by breaking His own rules, as He had done many times before.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the scene where Ai was in front of Alice's grave with Alice standing beside her...
The original Alice had already died. Then after class 3-4 wished for the incident to never happen (causing a time-loop to occur), Alice's soul was probably revived while his body was buried. Alice of course had no idea he died. So while he kept searching for a way to break the time-loop, he started to change and then he met Ai. Ai probably wished for the Alice she knew to come back to life. Thus the original Alice was still buried and the Alice whom Ai knew revived.

[This is just my theory though.]

Answer (score -1):

For Alice ai was somehow able to save him before 3-4 disappeared and brought him to the real world and the scene with them at Alice's grave showed Alice's original body which was buried 14 years before the series